# Which pairs of the following matrices are similar over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

$A =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$,
 $B =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$,

$C =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$, 
 $D =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$,

$E =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$, 
 $F =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$,

So far, I have found that $B$ is similar to $C$ and $A$ is similar to $E$ by using permutation matrices. One thing that is confusing me is that we're working in $\mathbb{R}$. I know that $A$ and $B$ are in Jordan Canonical Form and are therefore similar over $\mathbb{C}$. Can we say the same for $\mathbb{R}$? Also, I found that $F$ is not similar to any of the other matrices, since its minimal polynomial is degree 3 as opposed to degree 2. Any ideas on how to check if $D$ is similar to another matrix? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&2\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$